# ModuleNotFoundError - faker import at Jupyter notebook on Mac

Tags: jupyter, faker

I am trying to import faker from jupyter notebook on mac and failed.

It complains as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6235527da291> in <module>()
----> 1 from faker import Faker

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'faker'
```

I use pip install faker and the system says

```
Requirement already satisfied: faker in /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: text-unidecode in /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from faker)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.4 in /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from faker)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from faker)
```

I would be appreciated if anyone can help me out

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

- Solution1: you're using python3.6, so try `pip3` instead of `pip`
- Solution2: use a python3 virtual env like mentioned in [this tuto](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/generating-fake-data-for-python-unit-tests-with-faker)
- Solution3: this is another idea from [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/#How-to-use-Pip-from-the-Jupyter-Notebook) : use `python -m pip install <package>` rather than `pip install <package>`

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using Python python3.6, use `pip3 install Faker` instead of `pip install Faker`.